# How to make a dynamic memo in a class using delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a form class `TfrmWelcome` and I want to be able to dynamically add
a memo to it when a button is clicked in the main part of the form (`frmWelcome.MainPanelSourceEditor`).

My unsuccessful attempt at some code is below.  I get the error
"undeclared identifier WelcomeMemo".  How could I get this to compile and work?

```
type
  WelcomeMemo : TMemo;
  end;

implementation

procedure SetHelpWelcome;
begin
  WelcomeMemo : TMemo.Create(frmWelcome);
  with TMemo(FindComponent('WelcomeMemo')) do
  begin
    Parent := frmWelcome.MainPanelSourceEditor;
```

Comment: _"I really don't know what this line of code does, i just put it there to see if it would work"_, well, that might be the problem.

Comment: This code is complete nonsense.  Nothing about any of it makes any sense at all.  Throw it away and start with some tutorials.

Comment: What is your code *supposed* to do? FWIW, the very tiny little bit of code you have shown us is not even valid syntax. If you wrote code and don't even know what you wrote, then you need to stop in your tracks and go study how to write code in Delphi before you proceed.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Indeed, but personally I think these SA students starting out in Delphi (D7 I would guess) should be encouraged.  So I try to give them something which will work before sending them off to find a tutorial.

Comment: @martyna They should be encouraged to post good questions that will be useful to others. They should kit be encouraged to post like this. Close and downvote is the correct reaction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  95% of the time, I agree, especially about the idle OPs who can't be bothered to think themselves into the shoes of those who might answer.  But I think overt beginners can be cut a little slack.  My ten-year old is just starting out coding, and I've been surprised that he seems to find the most difficult thing is explaining what his problem is.  We were all there once.

Comment: @martyna This isn't the place for that. It's a resource for future visitors. This is a terrible question. If the asker wants help then that should happen somewhere else

Comment: I mean, I can see an up vote on the question. What could that be for? How can that be explained.

Comment: @MartynA Where does OP say that they're a student? What should that matter? What if OP was an equally enthused non-student? How is it helpful to encourage poor questions? How is it okay to suggest that we have the ability to read minds?

Comment: @JerryDodge:  I was guessing, apparently correctly at least so far as what the OP wanted to know, judging by her comment.  As to "student", have you not noticed that there is a continuous stream of qs from OPs in SA about Delphi + Pascal stuff that is obviously coursework and/or beginners' level, almost invariably for D7.  And the readership here obviously includes readers in that position, and SO is here just as much to help them as others.  IMO ...

Comment: @MartynA No, it's not so obvious to me. Apparently, you prefer to study who the OP is thoroughly before deciding how to respond. That's not how SO works.

Comment: @MartynA It doesn't matter who asks. We don't judge the question by differing standards for different askers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is to add a memo to your frmWelcome at runtime, a better (but still not very good) way to do it would be like this:

```
procedure SetHelpWelcome;
var
  WelcomeMemo : TMemo;
begin
  WelcomeMemo := TMemo.Create(frmWelcome);
  WelcomeMemo.Parent := frmWelcome.MainPanelSourceEditor;
  // set any other properties of WelcomeMemo here.
end;
```

This avoids the `with` (which you should never use especially if you are a beginner) and the completely avoidable `FindComponent` to find something you don't need to find in the first place if you capture it by the assignment to the `WelcomeMemo` local variable.

But that's still a fairly naff way of doing what you want.  It would be better to have the `WelcomeMemo` as a member of your form, and define a method of the form to create and initialise it; you could then call the method from the `OnClick` handler of the button you want to use to create it.  Something like (untested)

```
TfrmWelcome = Class(TForm)
private
  fWelcomeMemo : TMemo;
  procedure SetUpWelcomeMemo;
[...]
 end;

procedure TfrmWelcome.SetUpWelcomeMemo;
begin
  if fWelcomeMemo <> Nil then exit;  // to avoid creating it more than once
  fWelcomeMemo := TMemo.Create(Self);
  fWelcomeMemo.Parent := Self.MainPanelSourceEditor;
  // set any other properties of WelcomeMemo here.
end;
```

Apart from anything else, this avoids the memo's owner being set to the specific TfrmWelcome instance `frmWelcome`, which is an accident waiting to happen because it may not be the instance you are actually wanting to work with.

But like @J.. said, you really need to look at a beginner's tutorial if you are blundering around using trial and error the way it sounds like you are.

Comment: Thank you so much you guys. @JerryDodge I will thank you

Comment: @MissMassey Um, you're welcome?

Comment: @MissMassey:  Btw, if this answer helped you, please feel free to accept it by clicking the tick icon at its top lefthand corner.

Comment: Yes it did.. @MartynA